# Is .getTime() a function of new Date() or Date() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Specifically, which is correct?

`new Date().getTime();`

or

`(new Date()).getTime();`

Thanks

Comment: Both are correct, but that's because of the way `new` works. But it's a method of Date *instances*.

Comment: see both will work. Because getTime property is attached with date object. And in both case we are getting date object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, both are correct. I guess the question was more about the work of the `new` operator. The presence of it can be described by this example:

```
var constr = function() { 
   return { 
      getConstructor: function() { 
         return Date 
      } 
   }; 
};

console.log(new constr()); // Object { getConstructor: function }
console.log(new constr().getConstructor); // function () { return Date }
console.log(new constr().getConstructor()); // function Date() { [native code] }
console.log(new (constr().getConstructor())); // Wed Mar 25 2015 20:10:07 GMT+0500 (YEKT)
```

So if you want to create an instance of the constructor that is returned by a nested function, you should consider using `new (code that returns constructor)` rather than `new [code that eventually returns constructor]`. The latter won't work, as `new` will pick the first function call and create an instance.

Answer (score 3):

`new Date().getTime();`

After the `()` an object is created, therefore `getTime` is a method of the `Date` object which was instantiated with the `new` operator.

`(new Date()).getTime();`

That does the same thing as your first version. Both will achieve the result you desire.